# Declaring arrays similar to C style (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

In C a programmer can declare an array like so:

```
unsigned char Fonts[2][8] {
    [1] = {0, 31, 0, 31, 0, 31, 0, 31}
};
```

And element `[0]` is likely random bits. Is there a similar way in C++?

Comment: I take it that doesn't work in C++?

Comment: No it doesn't. Complains about the `[`.

Comment: gcc allows it, but g++ doesn't.

Comment: This was invented for C99 (at least, initializing members of a struct by name was. I've not come across it for arrays before, and I'm not quite enthusiastic enough to look it up right now). It's not in C++.

Comment: That's C99, which is not a part if the current C++. And the unitialized parts are not random bits, they are zeroes. Every time in C you initialize just a part of something, the rest is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
unsigned char Fonts[2][8] = {
    {0},
    {0, 31, 0, 31, 0, 31, 0, 31}
};
```

Comment: This zeroes out all Fonts[0][...]?

Comment: As indicated by BjoernD you can omit the single "0", but leaving it in keeps the code C89-compatible.

Comment: @John W Yes, as long as any initializer is specified, any values not given are set to zero.

Answer (score 6):

This works in C++:

```
unsigned char foo [2][8] = {
        {},
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'}
};
```

Here, `foo[0]` is zero-initialized as defined by the C++ standard (*§8.5.5* - default initialization for [POD types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structures) is zero-initialization). For non-POD-types the default constructor is called.

Comment: So this leaves foo[0][...] undefined?

Comment: No. foo[0] is zero-initialized as defined by the C++ standard (§8.5.5 - default initialization for non-POD types is zero-initialization).

Comment: Sorry, I meant default initialization for POD types. For non-POD, of course, the default constructor is called.

Comment: "default initialization for POD typs is zero-initialization". It's actually value-initialization that delegates to zero-initialization here, not default initialization. (your statement is true for '98, but not for '03 revision of C++)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do

```
unsigned char Fonts[2][8] {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 31, 0, 31, 0, 31, 0, 31}
};
```

?

Comment: Maybe its a very sparse array?

Comment: Because I'm borrowing C code that's already structured similar to the example I gave. I'm hoping for a simple solution that doesn't require me doing this by hand. :)

Comment: Why not keep the C code and make you program a combination of C and C++?

Comment: Richard, well I didn't have to do it by hand after all, so no huge deal. Small C program did it for me.